# run-time error '438' Object does'nt support this property or method

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to copy the contents of a range in my active workbook to another workbook, and I found a piece of vba code that i think fits perfectly for my needs.
Altough, everytime I try to run it, I receive the following error: run-time error '438' Object does'nt support this property or method.
I suppose the problem is the way I'm selecting the range in the destination workbook, but nothing os working.
Could anyone help?

Here is what I have:

```
Sub Retânguloarredondado1_Click()

Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String '
Dim TP As Worksheet

' Set path for Input & Output
fileInputpath = "C:\Users\Nuno Bonaparte\Desktop\"
Outputpath = "C:\Users\Nuno Bonaparte\Desktop\"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set InputFile = ActiveWorkbook
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "file2.xlsm")
Set TP = OutputFile.Worksheets("Folha1")

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile:
InputFile.Sheets("file2").Activate
InputFile.Sheets("file2").Range("A1:A12").Copy

'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
OutputFile.Sheets("Folha1").Activate
TP.Range("A1").PasteSpecialOutputFile.Save

'Close InputFile & OutputFile:
InputFile.Close
OutputFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: When you run the macro and get the error, which line of code does it highlight?

Comment: This one: "TP.Range("A1").PasteSpecialOutputFile.Save
"

Comment: You set the variable `OutputFile` as equal to an open command, but then you use it as the name of a workbook.  That is your issue.  You should also define your `InputFile`.  What are the names of the two files (workbooks)?

Comment: file1.xlsm and file2.xlsm

Comment: I'm having no issues with the InputFile, as it is my active workbook. When i run the code, the InputFile shows the selected range copied and then it opens the OutputFile, but it doesn't highlit the selected cell where i want to paste the content and stops immediatly.

Comment: Did you try the below code (answer)?  Where did an error occur (if any)?

Comment: Not working, and now, the excel instances abruptly close when i run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you get the same error with this code:

```
Sub Retânguloarredondado1_Click()

Dim Paths As String

' Set path
Paths = "C:\Users\Nuno Bonaparte\Desktop\"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Workbooks.Open(Paths & "file1.xlsm")
Workbooks.Open(Paths & "file2.xlsm")

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile:
Workbooks("file1.xlsm").Sheets("file2").Range("A1:A12").Copy

'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
Workbooks("file2.xlsm").Worksheets("Folha1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("file2.xlsm").Save

'Close InputFile & OutputFile without saving
InputFile.Close False
OutputFile.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Not working, and now, the excel instances abruptly close when i run the code

Comment: Updated some syntax.  Try now.

Comment: Think is solved. I believe Range does not support paste. I changed to pastespecial and it worked. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've changed this line : TP.Range("A1").PasteSpecialOutputFile.Save for this one: TP.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll and it worked. Then i saved the workbook just before the close command

Comment: Yep... saw that syntax error and had corrected that in my code.